# How create custom animated toggle background color react native

Tags: react-native, animation

**Hello! I recently started learning React Native and I want to make two colors constantly flash on this button ((( Please check my code, i can't get it to work. It should of course work on two platforms IOS & Android**

```
const InviteChildButton = ({ changeInvite }: IProps) => {
  const { invitation } = useTranslation();
  const { username } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.child);

  const animatedColor = new Animated.Value(0);
  const backgroundColorAnimation = animatedColor.interpolate(
    {
      inputRange: [0, 0.5,],
      outputRange: ['rgba(113, 255, 139, 0.1)', 'rgba(255, 169, 139, 0.1)']
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(backgroundColorAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      useNativeDriver:true
    }).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <CustomText
          style={styles.text}
          text={`${invitation} ${username}`}
          variant='h3'
          type='normal'
        />
      </View>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: backgroundColorAnimation }]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeInvite}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={Images.inviteLogoButton} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>

    </View>
  );
};

export default InviteChildButton;
```

Comment: could you wrap animated view with touchble rather than what you have
```<Touchble><Animatev.View></Touchble>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Animated.timing` expects **animated value**, try to change *backgroundColorAnimation* to *animatedColor* and disable native driver, I don't think it supports background color interpolation.